# Making API with authentication of an existing rails MVC app with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authentication, mobile, devise

I have a social web app in production made with Rails 4.1.6 (MVC) and I'm making a (non native) mobile version of it (Intel XDK). Currently, a user must sign in/up via email+password, Facebook or Google+ to access the app. I'm using Devise (>3.2) and omniauth.
After reading tons of Q/A, examples and tutorials my brain is full and, unlike Jimmy Cliff sing, I can't see clearly now... I have 2 questions:

1. what is the best solution(s) to create an API on top of this current app?
2. how to implement an auth solution so that existing users can sign in and new users can sign up to the mobile app with email+password as well as FB/G+ auth?

And of course, a user can sign in both to mobile and web app.
Thanks!